# Creating an Object List from another List Object LINQ Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, lambda

I am trying to add certain objects to another object. But I am getting an error in the Options section. I am quite simply trying to add certain stuff out of one object and into another.

Here is what my code looks like..

```
var responses = new Responses();
                form.Questions.ForEach(
                    q => responses.Questions.Add(new Models.Question()
                    {
                        QuestionId = Convert.ToInt32(q.Id),
                        Value = q.SingleAnswer,
                        Options = q.Options.ForEach( o => q.Options.Add(
                            new Option // <----FAILING HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            {
                                OptionId = 1,
                                Value = "test"
                            }
                            ))

                    })
                );
```

The error is

```
Argument type 'Web.Models.Option' is not assignable to parameter type QuestionOptionViewModel
```

MODELS:

```
public class Responses
    {
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }


public class QuestionOptionViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string QuestionType { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "text", ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "checkbox", ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string QuestionType { get; set; }

        public string SubType { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "singleAnswer", ErrorMessage = "Reqired Field")]
        public string SingleAnswer { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "radio", ErrorMessage = "Radio Reqired")]
        public int? SelectedRadio { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "select", ErrorMessage = "Selection Reqired")]
        public int? SelectedSelect { get; set; }

        public bool CheckboxError { get; set; }

        public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this isn't too misguided but I think you're going about this all wrong. You want to do a `Select` and assign the result to the questions property in responses. Here's a basic example;

```
var responses = new Responses();
    responses.Questions = form.Questions.Select(
                q => new Models.Question()
                {
                    QuestionId = Convert.ToInt32(q.Id),
                    Value = q.SingleAnswer,
                    Options = q.Options.Select(o =>
                        new Option
                        {
                            OptionId = (int) o.Id,
                            Value = o.Value
                        }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

I edited your code rather quickly so there is some potential that won't work as is (didn't compile or anything). But basically you use `Select` for projection, return a `List<Question>` and assign it to the `Questions` property. Don't try to do the adds in place. Besides that you never initialized the `Questions` list so even if that code compiled you'd get a `NullReferenceException`. Again, there are likely other problems with your code but I think you're fundamentally misusing `ForEach` when `Select` is actually the correct operation.

Comment: You need to do a `ToList` after the `Select` because `Options` is a `List<Option>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  One you are trying to change the collection you are iterating over with your `ForEach`.  And second you are trying to assign the result of that `ForEach`.  Instead you should use a `Select` and `ToList` to create a list to assign to `Options`.  If you change

```
Options = q.Options.ForEach( o => q.Options.Add(
      new Option 
      {
            OptionId = 1,
            Value = "test"
       }
       ))
```

to

```
Options = q.Options.Select( 
      new Option 
      {
            OptionId = 1,
            Value = "test"
       }
       ).ToList()
```

it should work